# convention for using link attribute in html list

Tags: javascript, html, tags

I was wondering if there I a correct order for the `<li>` and `<a>` tags when create lists as menus. i.e. every list item will also be a link.

I currently have a mixture of lists on my page some are images and some are texts

```
    <ul id="controls" class="menu-options hidden">
        <li><img title="Line Status" src="img/live.png" /></li>
        <li><img title="Station Information" src="img/info.png" /></li>
        <li><img id="direction-button" title="Route Finder" src="img/direction2.png" /></li>
        <li><img title="Show on map" src="img/find.png" /></li>
    </ul>
```

For this one I have set the response to activate on click of the li item

```
        <ul class="hidden">
            <a class="active" href="#"><li>Line Status</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Station Notifications</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>This Weekend</li></a>
        </ul>
```

And on this one I set the response to activate on click of the a item.

I am in the progress of cleaning my code and I am aware that it is good practise to make all of your interactive images/text activate on an `<a>` tag.
So the question is should my lists look like
a)

```
        <ul>
            <a href="#"><li>content</li></a>
            <a href=""><li>content</li></a>
        </ul>
```

or b)

```
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">content</a></li>
            <li><a href="">content</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: In order for it to validate, the valid children of a ul are a li or ol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the latter since `li` should be the only children of `ul`, and set a `display:block;` on your anchor tags to fill the li elements.

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">content</a></li>
  <li><a href="">content</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

The way I would think about it:

1) You are creating a list (ul tag).

2) You are creating a list item (li tag).

3) You are populating the list item with something (a tag).

so B

Comment: Valid HTML only allows `LI`s to be the direct descendants of `UL`s. Anything else mentioned is irrelevant.